# Как правильно проверить, отображается ли в текущий момент кастомный DialogFragment?

Tags: android, уведомления, dialogfragment

1) В моем приложении пользователю может приходить **множество нотификаций** из FCM.
2) Если у пользователя открыто приложении, ему необходимо отобразить **DialogFragment**
3) Если DialogFragment **уже отображен**, то при следующем приходе нотификации, **необходимо запретить повторное отображение** этого DialogFragment.

4) Мой код диалога:

```
public final class NotificationEventDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnKeyListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private Activity mCurrentActivity;
    private NotificationEventDialogListener mNotificationEventDialogListener;

    public interface NotificationEventDialogListener {
        void showEvent();
    }

    public NotificationEventDialog() {
    }

    public static NotificationEventDialog newInstance() {
        NotificationEventDialog notificationEventDialog = new NotificationEventDialog();
        notificationEventDialog.setCancelable(false);
        return notificationEventDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCurrentActivity = (Activity)context;
        try {
            mNotificationEventDialogListener = (NotificationEventDialogListener) mCurrentActivity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(mCurrentActivity.toString() + " должен реализовывать NotificationEventDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCurrentActivity);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_notification_event, null);

        Button btnNotificationEventYes = view.findViewById(R.id.notification_event_dialog_yes);
        btnNotificationEventYes.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btnNotificationEventNo = view.findViewById(R.id.notification_event_dialog_no);
        btnNotificationEventNo.setOnClickListener(this);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mCurrentActivity);
        builder.setView(view);

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getDialog().setOnKeyListener(this);
        }
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCurrentActivity = null;
        mNotificationEventDialogListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.notification_event_dialog_yes:
                dismiss();
                mNotificationEventDialogListener.showEvent();
                break;
            case R.id.notification_event_dialog_no:
                dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            dismiss();
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

5) При каждой нотификации из FCM, создаю диалоговое окно:

```
DialogFragment notificationEventDialog = NotificationEventDialog.newInstance();  
notificationEventDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");
```

6) Как проверить, **отображается ли в текущий момент уже DialogFragment**? Просто получается, что каждый раз создается новый обьект этого окна, сделать его как Singleton не подходит, т.к. *это ведет к утечке памяти*.

[Нашел ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36382705), в котором человек предлагает использовать Weak ссылки для решения этой проблемы:

> Also you can store a weak link to the shown dialog in that singletone
>   class. Using such method, you can detect is your dialog currently
>   shown or not.

Также был такой ответ, созданием метода внутри диалога и проверять его отображение:

> I suggest to save link to the dialog in single instance class. In that
>   instance create method ensureShowDialog(Context context). That method
>   would check is current shown dialog or not. If yes, you can show the
>   dialog. In another casr you can pass new data you to the dialog.

Но, если честно, не совсем могу понять как использовать эти подсказки на практике. Пожалуйста, можете помочь с этим или подсказать другой путь? Зараннее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте перед показом проверить диалог на `!null` по тегу (который у вас сейчас "", но напишите что-нибудь осмысленное)

Comment: @Jarvis_J Вы имеете ввиду задать тег для диалогового окна типа `notificationEventDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "df_notification_event");` а перед этим сделать типа `Fragment s = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("df_notification_event");` ??

Comment: `if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YOUR_TAG) == null) {show}`

Comment: @Jarvis_J к сожалению, данный способ не работает. Диалоговые окна создаются повторно. Может Вы знаете как реализовать тот способ, который приведен в цитатах?

Comment: вообще, у меня работает. При условии, что есть время отобразиться диалогу. Иначе (если зарядить все диалоги разом) он посчитает, что его нет. Как вариант навскидку: сделайте перед показом диалога микрозадержку (мне хватает 50 мсек) или проверяйте пришедшие уведомления, чтобы они не выкатывались разом.

Comment: @Jarvis_J у меня возникло 2 вопроса: 1) Что Вы пишете в `{show}`? 2) Микрозадержку с помщью `Thread.sleep(50)`?

Comment: dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG), задержка с помощью `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){ проверка и показ диалога}, 50);`, чтобы не вешать основной поток

Comment: @Jarvis_J спасибо, завтра попробую Ваш способ. Но все же интересно как это реализовать через Weak ссылки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первый вариант**. Проверка по тегу.

Перед показом диалога проверьте показывается ли диалог с таким тегом:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
            }
     }, 50) //задержка нужна, чтобы дать предыдущему диалогу время отрисоваться.      
}
```

**Второй вариант**. С флагом.

В диалоге:

```
public static boolean isShowing;

public static DialogCustom newInstance(...) {
    isShowing = true;
    ...
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    isShowing = false;
}
```

В активности:

```
if (!DialogCustom.isShowing) {
         DialogCustom.newInstance(...).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
}
```

**Третий вариант**. С onDismissListener.

Переменную диалога делаете глобальной и при вызове проверяете ее на null. И при закрытии диалога обнуляете.

```
DialogCustom dialogCustom;
```

При вызове:

```
if (dialogCustom ==null) {
     dialogCustom = DialogCustom.newInstance(...);
     dialogCustom.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),TAG);
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             dialogCustom.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                     dialogCustom = null;
                 }
                });
            }
     }, 5);//время на отрисовку, чтобы getDialog() не вернул null
}
```

Выбирайте наиболее удобный.